# Javascript exit page event

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so i have figured out how i can exit page with confirmation using window.onbeforeunload but how can i modify box that appears? Like adding css and html not only some text that says "Are you sure you want to exit this page?"

Comment: you cannot change this. Nor you can change any alert statement

Answer (score 2):

There is very little you can do with the `onbeforeunload` event.

This is to prevent JavaScript from *trapping* a user.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot modify the dialog style.

You can just try to customize it as better as you can for your purposes, for example:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return 'You have unsaved changes!';
    }
```

Read the documentation about this topic on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx)